# how can i use methods of that class such as getFormView(), processFormSubmission(... , ... , ... , ...) when rewriting my controllers?

Tags: java, spring

can any one suggest any documentations on how to re-write SimpleFormController sub-classes to use annotated controllers instead, like how can i use methods of that class such as `getFormView(), processFormSubmission(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object,
            BindException errors)` when rewriting my controllers?

The need to rewrite these classes come as a result of the need to upgrade to the recent versions of Spring like 4.1.4

Answer (score 0):

Like I have already stated, am upgrading my spring to 4.1.4-RELEASE and it looks like the SimpleFormController class was totally removed preceeding it's deprecation in 3